# Having Issue on Using a Loop Inside a jQuery .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two arrays as `state` and `memlist` and as you can see I am loading the elements of `memlist` to `#list` ul. This is working by using the `.each()` function but I still need to load the elemnt of `state` as a class defintion into `<li>`s like following:

```
memlist.append($( '<li class="'+ state[i] +'">' + value + '</li>' ));
```

can you please let me know how to do this in jQuery?

```
var memlist = $( "#list" );

var states = ['one','two','three'];
var members = [ "John", "Steve", "Ben", "Damon", "Ian" ];
$.each(members,function( index, value ){
  memlist.append($( "<li>" + value + "</li>" ));
});
```

Thanks

Comment: `states != state` so `states[i]` not `state[i]` - `memlist.append($( '<li class="'+ states[i] +'">' + value + '</li>' ));`

Comment: memlist.append($( "<li>" + value + "</li>" ).addClass(states[index]));

Comment: How do you want *three* states to match up to *five* members?

Comment: Yeah, how you want to add those classes, to which criteria ?

Comment: may be starting over again @nnnnnn. like `1,2,3,1,2` just a guess.

Comment: Hey yo need to make sure you have same number of elements in both arrays.

Comment: @Jai - that was my guess too, and easy enough with the % operator, but I couldn't be bothered writing up an answer unless the OP clarified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it reaches the states length it start over

```js
var memlist = $( "#list" );

var states = ['one','two','three'];
var members = [ "John", "Steve", "Ben", "Damon", "Ian", "test"];
var counter = 0;
$.each(members,function( index, value ){
  //console.log(counter);
  memlist.append($( "<li class="+states[counter]+">" + value + "</li>" ));
  counter++;
  if(counter == states.length){
    counter=0;
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure You have same number of elements in `states` and `members`.
If they are so then you can do the following.

```
var states = ['one','two','three'];
var members = [ "John", "Steve", "Ben", "Damon", "Ian" ];
$.each(members,function( index, value ){
// Now index will be helpful to traverse through states array so 
   memlist.append("<li class = '"+states[index]+"'>" + value + "</li>")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried by this is ok..

```
$.each(members,function( index, value ){  
  var clas =(index < states.length) ? states[index] :  null;
  memlist.append('<li class="'+clas+'">' + value + '</li>' );
});
```

Comment: what would `Damon` and `Ian` get if executed this code.

Answer (score 0):

`var states = [one,two,three];
    var members = [ "John", "Steve", "Ben", "Damon", "Ian" ];
    var element_html="";
    for(var i=0 ; i < members.length ; i++) {
    element_html += <li class=;
    element_html += state[k];
    element_html += >;
    element_html += value;
    element_html +=</li>;
    }
    $("#list").html(element_html);`

```
k is what ever you want to choose from state list
```